# Import SASS variables into Material UI theme with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, material-ui, next.js

In my project I have the following files:

**materialTheme.ts**

```
import { createMuiTheme, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#209dd2", contrastText: "#fff" },
    secondary: { main: "#81B44C", contrastText: "#fff" },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

**palette.scss**

```
$primary: #209dd2;
$secondary: #81b44c;
$contrast: #fff;

:export {
  primary: $primary;
  secondary: $secondary;
  contrast: $contrast;
}
```

I want to de-duplicate these files. I thought I could import the variables from **palette.scss** into **materialTheme.ts** but Next.JS throws an error about only importing global CSS into **_app.tsx**

**materialTheme.ts (not working)**

```
import { createMuiTheme, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import palette from "./palette.scss";

const theme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: palette.primary, contrastText: palette.contrast },
    secondary: { main: palette.secondary, contrastText: palette.contrast },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Is there any way I can make NextJS ignore this error just for **materialTheme.ts** and correctly import the variables?

I'd imagine I could definite `const theme` inside my **_app.tsx** and then import **palette.scss** there but ideally I'd like to maintain separate files for the theme and the app.

Alternatively, is there any pattern in which I can import the Javascript variables into the SCSS file or the SCSS variables into the Javascript file whilst adhering to this no global CSS rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename `palette.scss` to `palette.module.scss` to follow the CSS modules naming convention used by Next.js. This tells Next.js that the Sass file is locally scoped and can be imported anywhere in your app.

Comment: Oh my god, that was so obvious! Thank you. For some reason, despite using modules throughout the project for components and pages, I didn't think to apply them to the theme too